Can I upgrade all CC 3.0 licenses to 4.0 counterparts when creating a joint dataset?
I am planning on creating a dataset which contains data with different licenses. I decided to create differently-licensed versions of my dataset that contain different combinations of data from different licenses. I based the combination on this article. Hence, the following versions are planned, including elements of the licenses noted below each version:

public-domain will contain work licensed under:

public-domain


cc0-1.0 will contain work licensed under:

public-domain
cc0-1.0


cc-by will contain work licensed under:

public-domain
cc0-1.0
cc-by


cc-by-sa will contain work licensed under:

public-domain
cc0-1.0
cc-by
cc-by-sa


cc-by-nc will contain work licensed under:

public-domain
cc0-1.0
cc-by
cc-by-nc


cc-by-nc-sa will contain work licensed under:

public-domain
cc0-1.0
cc-by
cc-by-nc
cc-by-nc-sa



It seems clear to me that I can combine works released solely under 3.0 versions and works released solely under 4.0 versions. E.g., I would combine cc-by-3.0 and cc-by-nc-3.0 as cc-by-nc-3.0; or cc-by-nc-4.0 and cc-by-nc-sa-4.0 as cc-by-nc-sa-4.0.
However, can I also combine both works with 3.0 licenses and works with 4.0 licenses into a single 4.0 license? I only found information on SA licenses. Nevertheless, can I, e.g., combine a work licensed under cc-by-3.0 and a work licensed under cc-by-nc-4.0 and release it as cc-by-nc-4.0?

The very article you've linked to says you cannot combine CC-BY-SA and CC-BY-NC-SA. Why do you believe you can do this?

@PhilipKendall Thank you for pointing that out, I corrected the possible combinations and examples!

Take a closer look. A collection of facts (data) might not even be copyrightable, so the "licenses to the original collections" might very well be moot anyway.
As a general rule, you can't "change license", only the owner of the rights can (re)license any work under a different license. The GPL is explicit in this, it states e.g. "you can use this under GPLv2, or, at your option, under any later version of GPL". Check if the licenses you cite allow such changes, or combining with others. Often it is enough that the licenses don't contradict and you are allowed to use in combination, but each piece stays under the original license.
I am not a lawyer, so the above is a layman's take. It is a very complicated area.
